# PDF electronic signature ByteRange

Tags: pdf, structure, signature

I'm working on some PDF files and I'm not finding a clear explanation for the questions posted here. On a digitally signed PDF file we have the below temporary signature:

```
<< /Type /Sig /Filter /Adobe.PPKLite /SubFilter /adbe.pkcs7.detached/ByteRange[O1 L1 O2 L2]                  /Contents<0000....0000>
```

O1 = offset 1 (zero)

L1 = Length 1 (Content length before signature)

O2 = offset 2 (L1 + signature length)

L2 = Length 2 (Content length after signature)

I have these questions:

1 - The content to be "hashed" should include "<" and ">" (In the begin and the end of signature placeholder 0000....0000)?

2 - The length of signature is 11742? Does this includes "<" and ">"?

3 - On the **ByteRange** the second parameter is the length from the beginning of file up to "<" (before signature placeholder 0000....0000) or including it? Same as on previous question, the last parameter on **ByteRange** does includes the ">" character (at the end of signature placeholder 0000....0000)?

If someone can redirect me to a technical manual regarding this it will be very helpful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After reading the technical manuals and experimenting with PDF now I have the answers.

> 1 - The content to be "hashed" should include "<" and ">" (In the begin and the end of signature placeholder 0000....0000)?

No, **"<" and ">" and should not be part of the data to be "hashed/signed"**. After the signing process "<" and ">" should be used as a delimiters for hexadecimal signature. Example: /Contents<3255....0000>

> 2 - The length of signature is 11742? Does this includes "<" and ">"?

Not necessary. As long this length of "signature placeholder" is longer then **signed** and **timestamped** data.

> 3 - On the ByteRange the second parameter is the length from the beginning of file up to "<" (before signature placeholder 0000....0000) or including it? Same as on previous question, the last parameter on ByteRange does includes the ">" character (at the end of signature placeholder 0000....0000)?

The second parameter is the offset of "<" (before signature placeholder) or, using the same logic, the content length from the beginning of file up to "<" (Without including it)

The last parameter does not include the ">" to calculate the length of the remaining data.

Additional clarification after the comments of mkl (https://stackoverflow.com/users/1729265/mkl)

> O2 = offset 2 (L1 + signature length)

O2 = offset 2 = L1 + signature length + 2. This because the placeholder includes "<" and ">"

EXAMPLE:

```
{100-BYTES-DATA-BEFORE}<0000....0000>{50-BYTES-DATA-AFTER}
```

Data to be hashed/signed/timestamped

```
{100-BYTES-DATA-BEFORE} + {50-BYTES-DATA-AFTER}
```

Signature placeholder = 11742 Bytes (11742 zeros)

```
ByteRange[O 100 11844 50]
```

After data sign and/or timestamp:

```
{100-BYTES-DATA-BEFORE} + < + 4321....0000 + > + {50-BYTES-DATA-AFTER}
```

[PDF32000](https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/pdf/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf)

Comment: Your resolution of 2 is puzzling: In your question text you wrote *"O2 = offset 2 (L1 + signature length)"*. Put like that the "signature length" is exactly the signature placeholder length. In your answer, though, you suddenly appear to mean by "length of signature" the size (written in hex chars?) of the signature container embedded in the placeholder which of course is smaller than the placeholder because the placeholder (as you have found out) includes the '<' and '>' brackets.

Comment: O2 = L1 + signature length + 2. I forgot to comment on that. I have updated the response with your contribution. Thank You

Comment: https://www.adobe.com/devnet-docs/etk_deprecated/tools/DigSig/Acrobat_DigitalSignatures_in_PDF.pdf (sect. 6.2.1) seems to contradict the accepted answer - it requires the < and > to be the hashed/signed data.

Comment: @MikeKaganski  *"Acrobat_DigitalSignatures_in_PDF.pdf (sect. 6.2.1) seems to contradict the accepted answer - it requires the < and > to be the hashed/signed data."* Indeed, there is an error in that old Adobe document. The angled brackets must not be part of the signed byte ranges.